# AppleScript: set Microsoft Excel cell's background color

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

Using AppleScript, how can I change the background color of "cells ranging from A3 to E3" to light grey?

I still want the font to be in black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two caveats with this answer: You didn't specify which version of Excel, and the following was tested in v2004.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set theRange to range "A3:E3"
    set interiorObject to interior object of theRange
    set color index of interiorObject to 5 -- '5' is only a dummy value; change as needed.
end tell
```

Per the dictionary, `color index` is "the color is specified as an index value into the current color palette". In other words, the color index that is light gray in your install maybe different elsewhere.