# Set theme color of Format cell color

Tags: excel, applescript, excel-2008

In Office 2008, how may I set the theme color in conditional formatting using AppleScript?

```
tell format color of color scale criterion 1 of colorcellObject
set theme color to first accent theme color
end tell
```

This script through errors (set theme color object is not defined).

[image: SO13583113 question example]

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Applescript (using VBA in Windows myself), but I would suggest using the {[0-255],[0-255],[0-255]} codes for the RGB colors.

These can be hardcoded if you know the codes beforehand, possibly you could use a small section of your excel to apply the appropriate colors to and refer to those in your script.

For the script follow along the lines of this:
[AppleScript: set Microsoft Excel cell's background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616872/apple-script-microsoft-excel-cells-back-ground-color)